# Need to remove value in emailattribute AD/powershell

Tags: powershell

Hi i need to set the emailattribute to null/nothing on users. I have created this:

```powershell
Get-ADGroupMember -Identity "testgrupp" | Get-ADUser -Properties samaccountname | Foreach {
Set-ADUser -Identity $_ -EmailAddress ("")
}
```

But it fails, i think its the last part that's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Substitute `("")` for `$null`:

```powershell
Get-ADGroupMember -Identity "testgrupp" | 
Get-ADUser -Properties samaccountname | Foreach {
    Set-ADUser -Identity $_ -EmailAddress $null
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A couple of ways to fix this:

Use the -ExpandProperty parameter of Select-Object so you only get the samaccountname strings:

```
Get-ADGroupMember -Identity "testgrupp" |
 Get-ADUser -Properties samaccountname | 
 Select -ExpandProperty samaccountname |
 Foreach {
          Set-ADUser -Identity $_ -EmailAddress ("")
        }
```

or reference the samaccountname property in your Set-ADUser:

```
Get-ADGroupMember -Identity "testgrupp" | 
Get-ADUser -Properties samaccountname | 
Foreach {
         Set-ADUser -Identity $_.samaccountname -EmailAddress ("")
        }
```

Comment: Neither of those worked :( I get errors on "Set-Aduser"